# How to get the right application path in .net core 1.1 when run command "dotnet project.dll"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

The "dotnet" command get wrong current application path in .net core 1.1

Example

My project code path: `"e:/master/net/demo/demoMvc.csproj"`.

My project publish path: `"e:/master/net/demo/publish"`.

When I run command `"dotnet demoMvc.dll"` or `"dotnet e:/master/net/demo/publish/demoMvc.dll"` in `"e:/master/net/demo/publish"`, it is all right.

But when run command `"dotnet e:/master/net/demo/publish/demoMvc.dll"` not in `"e:/master/net/demo/publish"` this path, it is always wrongs.

My code:

[image]

The error image:

[image]

Causing more errors: all page not found !

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

Comment: Can you add your project.cs line 10 to question? or all main function?

Comment: @msd Yes, has been added.

Answer (score -1):

```
 var path = Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "images");
```

this go in wwwroot -> images